# How can I use PCRE to get all match groups?

Tags: c, regex, pcre

I am inexperienced with using C, and I need to use PCRE to get matches.
Here is a sample of my source code:

```
int test2()
{
    const char *error;
    int   erroffset;
    pcre *re;
    int   rc;
    int   i;
    int   ovector[OVECCOUNT];

    char *regex = "From:([^@]+)@([^\r]+)";
    char str[]  = "From:regular.expressions@example.com\r\n"\
                  "From:exddd@43434.com\r\n"\
                  "From:7853456@exgem.com\r\n";

    re = pcre_compile (
             regex,       /* the pattern */
             0,                    /* default options */
             &error,               /* for error message */
             &erroffset,           /* for error offset */
             0);                   /* use default character tables */

    if (!re) {
        printf("pcre_compile failed (offset: %d), %s\n", erroffset, error);
        return -1;
    }

    rc = pcre_exec (
        re,                   /* the compiled pattern */
        0,                    /* no extra data - pattern was not studied */
        str,                  /* the string to match */
        strlen(str),          /* the length of the string */
        0,                    /* start at offset 0 in the subject */
        0,                    /* default options */
        ovector,              /* output vector for substring information */
        OVECCOUNT);           /* number of elements in the output vector */

    if (rc < 0) {
        switch (rc) {
            case PCRE_ERROR_NOMATCH:
                printf("String didn't match");
                break;

            default:
                printf("Error while matching: %d\n", rc);
                break;
        }
        free(re);
        return -1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < rc; i++) {
        printf("%2d: %.*s\n", i, ovector[2*i+1] - ovector[2*i], str + ovector[2*i]);
    }
}
```

In this demo, the output is only:

`0: From:regular.expressions@example.com`
 `1: regular.expressions`
 `2: example.com`

I want to output all of the matches; how can I do that?

Comment: Don’t use a regular expression but a real parser. The mail protocoal allows more than just the plain mailbox address.

Comment: This is a demo for pcre, i just want to know how to use pcre in matching groups.
Thanks for your comment.

Comment: you should refer to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785557/pcre-match-all-groups-in-c

Comment: well, I'm late here but the documentations of pcre provides a sample that you may make a benefit from, https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2sample.html , it's now pcre2 by the way.

Answer (score 9):

I use a class to wrap PCRE to make this easier, but after the pcre_exec, the ovector contains the substring indexes you need to find the matches within the original string.

So it would be something like:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "pcre.h"

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char *error;
    int   erroffset;
    pcre *re;
    int   rc;
    int   i;
    int   ovector[100];

    char *regex = "From:([^@]+)@([^\r]+)";
    char str[]  = "From:regular.expressions@example.com\r\n"\
                  "From:exddd@43434.com\r\n"\
                  "From:7853456@exgem.com\r\n";

    re = pcre_compile (regex,          /* the pattern */
                       PCRE_MULTILINE,
                       &error,         /* for error message */
                       &erroffset,     /* for error offset */
                       0);             /* use default character tables */
    if (!re)
    {
        printf("pcre_compile failed (offset: %d), %s\n", erroffset, error);
        return -1;
    }

    unsigned int offset = 0;
    unsigned int len    = strlen(str);
    while (offset < len && (rc = pcre_exec(re, 0, str, len, offset, 0, ovector, sizeof(ovector))) >= 0)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < rc; ++i)
        {
            printf("%2d: %.*s\n", i, ovector[2*i+1] - ovector[2*i], str + ovector[2*i]);
        }
        offset = ovector[1];
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But i still do not know how to output all the matches.

Comment: Are you only getting the first set of matcheS?  You will have to specify the PCRE_MULTILINE option when you compile the regex.  See: http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt for details.  I'll update the example.

Comment: I've updated the code in my answer to do what I think you need.  I'm admittedly not a PCRE expert as I've only used it through a wrapper so I'm not familiar with it's intricacies.  I would think there would be a way to do this with 1 call to exec. and have it return the ovector array with string indexes to all the matches.  This should do the trick though.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, i will read the PCRE documents again.

Answer (score 7):

note: last parameter of pcre_exec() must be element-count, not sizeof() !  ( http://www.pcre.org/readme.txt )

Comment: Also: element count must be a multiple of 3 (e.g. 90  not  100 !)