# Strip numbers from a string in C

Tags: c, string, numbers, strip, digit

I'm looking for a simple solution for stripping numbers from a string.
Example: "GA1UXT4D9EE1" => "GAUXTDEE"

The occurrence of the numbers inside the string is erratic hence I cannot rely on functions such as scanf().

I'm new at programming in C.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: There is no simple solution for string operations in C. :p
Post your code!

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044081/how-to-do-regex-string-replacements-in-pure-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char stringToStrip[128];
char stripped[128];
strcpy(stringToStrip,"GA1UXT4D9EE1");

const int stringLen = strlen(stringToStrip);
int j = 0;
char currentChar;

for( int i = 0; i < stringLen; ++i ) {
    currentChar = stringToStrip[i];
    if ((currentChar < '0') || (currentChar > '9')) {
        stripped[j++] = currentChar;
    }
}

stripped[j] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 3):

I will give you some tips:

- You need to creat a new string.
- Iterat over the original string.
- Check if the current character is between the [ascii values of numbers](http://www.google.co.il/imgres?imgurl=http://www.cdrummond.qc.ca/cegep/informat/professeurs/alain/images/ASCII1.GIF&imgrefurl=http://www.cdrummond.qc.ca/cegep/informat/professeurs/alain/files/ascii.htm&h=600&w=560&sz=22&tbnid=_mIC2A1Zjxd_9M%3a&tbnh=84&tbnw=78&zoom=1&usg=__mxmLfS2f5Pd8TmXVveL21e_W1Cs=&docid=iqSox57x8gJPkM&sa=X&ei=kHHcUe2hMcOQtAa0z4GgBg&ved=0CDsQ9QEwAw&dur=368)
- If not, add it to the new string.

Comment: Don't assume ASCII, use [`isdigit`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/)

Comment: @Anton If you want have more fun with coding you can try saving the stripped version of string in the original string.

Answer (score 1):

iterate through the string and check for the ascii value.

```
for(i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
{
  if(str[i] >= 48 && str[i] <= 57)
  {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Comment: I do not recommend using bare numbers. Much better to use the appropriate character constants: `if (str[i] >='0' && str[i] <= '9')`... Alternatively, `#include <ctype.h>` and use the `isdigit()` macro.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree that walking through would be an easy way to do it, but there is also an easier function to do this.  You can use isdigit().  C++ documentation has an awesome example. (Don't worry, this also works in c.)

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/

Comment: [http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/isdigit.html](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/isdigit.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to do it.

```
int i;
int strLength = strlen(OriginalString);
int resultPosCtr = 0;

char *result = malloc(sizeof(char) * strLength);//Allocates room for string. 

for(i = 0; i < strLength; i++){
    if(!isdigit(OriginalString[i])){
         result[resultPosCtr] = OriginalString[i];
         resultPosCtr++;
    }
}
result[resultPosCtr++] = '\0'; //This line adds the sentinel value A.K.A the NULL Value that marks the end of a c style string.
```

Everyone has it right.

1. Create a new char[] A.K.A. C style string.
2. Iterate over the original string
3. Check to see if the character at that iteration is a number
4. if not add to new string