# Working example of substitution using PCRS

Tags: c, replace, pcre

I need to to substitution in a string in C. It was recommended in one of the answers here [How to do regex string replacements in pure C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044081/how-to-do-regex-string-replacements-in-pure-c) to use the PCRS library. I downloaded PCRS from here ftp://ftp.csx.cam.ac.uk/pub/software/programming/pcre/Contrib/ but I'm confused as to how to use it. Below is my code (taken from another SE post)

```
            const char *error;
            int   erroffset;
            pcre *re;
            int   rc;
            int   i;
            int   ovector[100];

            char *regex = "From:([^@]+).*";
            char str[]  = "From:regular.expressions@example.com\r\n";
            char stringToBeSubstituted[] = "gmail.com";

            re = pcre_compile (regex,          /* the pattern */
                               PCRE_MULTILINE,
                               &error,         /* for error message */
                               &erroffset,     /* for error offset */
                               0);             /* use default character tables */
            if (!re)
            {
                printf("pcre_compile failed (offset: %d), %s\n", erroffset, error);
                return -1;
            }

            unsigned int offset = 0;
            unsigned int len = strlen(str);
            while (offset < len && (rc = pcre_exec(re, 0, str, len, offset, 0, ovector, sizeof(ovector))) >= 0)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < rc; ++i)
                {
                    printf("%2d: %.*s\n", i, ovector[2*i+1] - ovector[2*i], str + ovector[2*i]);
                }
                offset = ovector[1];
            }
```

As opposed to 'pcre_compile' and 'pcre_exec' what functions do I need to use from PCRS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply follow the instructions in the `INSTALL` file:

> To build PCRS, you will need pcre 3.0 or later and gcc.
>
> Installation is easy: ./configure && make && make install
>   Debug mode can be enabled with --enable-debug.
>
> There is a simple demo application (pcrsed) included.

PCRS provides the following functions documented in the man page `pcrs.3`:

- `pcrs_compile`
- `pcrs_compile_command`
- `pcrs_execute`
- `pcrs_execute_list`
- `pcrs_free_job`
- `pcrs_free_joblist`
- `pcrs_strerror`

Here's an [online version](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/45/idpl/3372325/numer/3/nazwa/pcrs) of the man page. To use these functions, include the header file `pcrs.h` and link your program against the PCRS library using the linker flag `-lpcrs`.