# How to match all substring by pcre_get_subtring_list

Tags: c, regex, pcre

Like this question:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421785/how-can-i-use-pcre-to-get-all-match-groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421785/how-can-i-use-pcre-to-get-all-match-groups?newreg=6dee25cbd7424887a6d97f1e97e788ef)

To get all matched substring, I know the way by loop here, but...how to get them by function `pcre_get_substring_list`?

here is my code example to get each string separated from space :

```
#include <pcre.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

    pcre*        compile;
    pcre_extra*  extra;;
    int          res;
    int          ovector[30];
    const char* pattern="\\S+";
    const char*  errptr;
    const char*  match[30];
    const char** match_list = match;
    int          erroffset;

    char*        test_str = "hello world , pcre example!";

    compile = pcre_compile(pattern, PCRE_MULTILINE,
                           &errptr, &erroffset,
                           NULL);
    if ( compile == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Could not compile '%s' : %s\n", pattern, errptr);
        exit(1);
    }

    extra = pcre_study(compile, 0, &errptr);
    if ( errptr != NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Could not study '%s' : %s\n", pattern, errptr);
        exit(1);
    }

    res = pcre_exec(compile,
                    extra,
                    test_str,
                    strlen(test_str),
                    0,
                    0,
                    ovector,
                    sizeof(ovector));
    if ( res == 0 ) {
        res = 30/3;
    }

    if ( res > 0 ) {
        pcre_get_substring_list(test_str, ovector, res, &match_list);
        printf("buffer : %s\n", test_str);
        printf("match  :\n");
        for ( int i = 0; match_list[i]; ++ i )
            printf("%9s%s\n", " ", match_list[i]);
        printf("\n");
        if ( match_list )
            pcre_free_substring_list(match_list);
    }
    printf("\n");

    if (compile)
        pcre_free(compile);

    if (extra)
        pcre_free(extra);

}
```

**print out**:

> buffer : hello world , pcre example!
>   match  :
>
> > hello

**expected**:

> buffer : hello world , pcre example!
>    match  :
>
> > hello
> >     world
> >     ,
> >     pcre
> >     example!

Thanks for any little help !

Comment: Your question is unclear. The [docs are here](http://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcreapi.html#SEC18), what  *exactly* is the problem?

Comment: I used command `man` already , the question is -the result I want to get : `{"hello", "world", ",", "pcre", "example!"}`; actually :`"hello"`.