# Tokenizing a string with a regular expression

Tags: regex, tokenize, pcre

Suppose I have a string like this: `abc def ghi jkl` (I put a space at the end for the sake of simplicity but it doesn't really matter for me) and I want to capture its "chunks" as follows:

```
abc

def

ghi

jkl
```

if and only if there are 1-4 "chunks" in the string. I have already tried the following regex:

```
^([^ ]+ ){1,4}$
```

at Regex101.com but it only captures the last occurrence. A warning about it is issued:

> A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data

How to correct the regular expression to achieve my goal?

Comment: This is an XY problem. Split/explode the string with whitespace and check if the resulting array contains 4 non-empty elements. However, it is possible to check and *match multiple consequent occurrences* (not capture) with PCRE, not POSIX one.

Comment: Ok, so I could do this "by hand" using just the programming language and not involving regular expressions, but is there a more automatic solution? In fact it is intended to be a part of a more complicated expression. PCRE is acceptable for me.

Comment: If your executable only allows accessing capturing group values, there is no solution that will work for you.

Comment: Could you explain the PCRE solution? I added my comment before your edit...

Comment: See [`(?:^(?=\s*\S+(?:\s+\S+){3}\s*$)|\G(?!^))\s*\K\S+`](https://regex101.com/r/uxhokw/1).

Comment: Looks respectable :) But it captures exactly 4 times, not 1-4...

Comment: Not a problem, really, the limiting quantifier is a flexible construct - [`(?:^(?=\s*\S+(?:\s+\S+){0,3}\s*$)|\G(?!^))\s*\K\S+`](https://regex101.com/r/uxhokw/2).

Comment: Magic, but works - thanks very much! I suppose You allow to freely use this expression in my program?

Comment: It took me 4 minutes to write it :) Sure. I will post an answer then, if it works for you.

Comment: Thank You :) Works good. It's a good argument to switch to PCRE, by the way.

Comment: If you can it might be best to switch to .NET regex that supports capture collection stack.

Comment: I don't use .NET, but there's no problem - the solution is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have no access to the code, the only solution you might use is a regex based on the `\G` operator that will only allow consecutive matches and a lookahead anchored at the start that will require 1 to 4 non-whitespace chunks in the string.

```
(?:^(?=\s*\S+(?:\s+\S+){0,3}\s*$)|\G(?!^))\s*\K\S+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uxhokw/2)

**Details**:

- `(?:^(?=\s*\S+(?:\s+\S+){0,3}\s*$)|\G(?!^))` - a custom boundary that checks if:

  - `^(?=\s*\S+(?:\s+\S+){0,3}\s*$)` - the string start position (`^`) that is followed with 1 to 4 non-whitespace chunks, separated with 1+ whitespaces, and trailing/leading whitespaces are allowed, too
  - `|` - or
  - `\G(?!^)` - the current position at the end of the previous successful match (`\G` also matches the start of a string, thus we have to use the negative lookahead to exclude that matching position, since there is a separate check performed)
- `\s*`  - zero or more whitespaces
- `\K` -  a match reset operator discarding all the text matched so far
- `\S+` - 1 or more characters other than whitespace

Comment: There's a problem with the expression, though. It works fine at regex101.com, but used inside a C++ piece of code (using the "plain" C interface) matches only the fist token, i.e. the function pcre_exec() returns 1. For example, for "abc def ghi" it would return just "abc". Any help?

Comment: This is unrelated to my answer, but you may have a look at [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1421923/3832970), I think you will find the solution to your new problem there.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done on linux using tr:

```
tr -sc 'a-zA-Z' '\n' < text.txt > out_text.txt
```

where in a text.txt file is your string to be normalized.

Comment: The expression is embedded in a regular executable, so I'd not like to do this.