# Using pcre_get_substring_list, match all pattern inside of string and return in array in C with PCRE?

Tags: c, regex, pcre

I need to use C in Linux with PCRE to match in this string "`<test>a</test> <test>b</test> <test>c</Test>`"  to get the letters a, b, and c.
I found this script in stackoverflow, it is  good but does not work for all the matches. Only the first matches. Why?

````
/*
*   gcc pcre1.c -lpcre   
*/     
#include <pcre.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    pcre*        compile;
    pcre_extra*  extra;;
    int          res;
    int          ovector[30];
    const char* pattern="(?i)<test>(.*?)</test>";
    const char*  errptr;
    const char*  match[30];
    const char** match_list = match;
    int          erroffset;
    char*        test_str = "<test>a</test> <test>b</test> <test>c</Test>";

    compile = pcre_compile(pattern, PCRE_MULTILINE,&errptr,&erroffset,NULL);
    if ( compile == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Could not compile '%s' : %s\n", pattern, errptr);
        exit(1);
    }

    extra = pcre_study(compile, 0, &errptr);
    if ( errptr != NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Could not study '%s' : %s\n", pattern, errptr);
        exit(1);
    }
    res = pcre_exec(compile,extra,test_str,strlen(test_str),0,0,ovector,sizeof(ovector));
    if ( res == 0 ) {
        res = 30/3;
    }
    if ( res > 0 ) {
        pcre_get_substring_list(test_str, ovector, res, &match_list);
        printf("buffer : %s\n", test_str);
        printf("match  :\n");
        for ( int i = 0; match_list[i]; ++ i ) {
            printf("%9s%s\n", " ", match_list[i]);
        printf("\n");
        }
        if ( match_list )
            pcre_free_substring_list(match_list);
    }
    printf("\n");
    if (compile)
        pcre_free(compile);
    if (extra)
        pcre_free(extra);

}```

thanks
````

Comment: Using `<test>(.*?)</test>` captures 0 or more characters in capture group 1. If you want to match a single character, then you can use for example `<test>(.)</test>` or a bit more restrictive `<test>[a-z]</test>` to match a char in the range of a-z using a character class. Or use `[abc]` to match only one of the listed characters.

Comment: thanks  for reply , but  also with <test>(.)</test>  return only  first sentence  a  and  not return a b c

Comment: Perhaps this page is helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421785/how-can-i-use-pcre-to-get-all-match-groups

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code slightly, but this works as you expect now:

```
% ./pcre1
a
b
c
```

I'll list the changes and why I made them:

- We will be using `ovector` before it it is set initially, so zero out.
  **`int ovector[30] = {0};`**
- The `pcre_get_substring()` will be easier for you to use for this purpose, so I switched away from `pcre_get_substring_list()`.
- We didn't need match[], as `pcre_get_substring()` calls `pcre_malloc()`.
- The variable match_list must be `char*` as we are passing it as `&match_list`.
  **`const char* match_list;`**
- The function `pcre_exec()` expects ovecsize to be a multiple of 3.
  **`3*(sizeof(ovector)/3)`**
- I wrapped the `pcre_exec()` call  in a while loop.
- I used `pcre_get_substring()`, `printf()`, and `pcre_free_substring()` instead.

```
//   gcc pcre1.c -lpcre
#include <pcre.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    pcre*        compile;
    pcre_extra*  extra;;
    int          res;
    int          ovector[30] = {0};
    const char*  pattern="(?i)<test>(.*?)</test>";
    const char*  errptr;
    const char*  match_list;
    int          erroffset;
    char*        test_str = "<test>a</test> <test>b</test> <test>c</Test>";

    compile = pcre_compile(pattern, PCRE_MULTILINE,&errptr,&erroffset,NULL);
    if ( compile == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Could not compile '%s' : %s\n", pattern, errptr);
        exit(1);
    }

    extra = pcre_study(compile, 0, &errptr);
    if ( errptr != NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Could not study '%s' : %s\n", pattern, errptr);
        exit(1);
    }
    while ((res = pcre_exec(compile, extra, test_str, strlen(test_str), ovector[1], 0, ovector, 3*(sizeof(ovector)/3))) >= 0) {
        if (pcre_get_substring(test_str, ovector, res, 1, &match_list) >= 0) {
            printf("%s\n", match_list);
            pcre_free_substring(match_list);
        }
    }
    if (compile)
        pcre_free(compile);
    if (extra)
        pcre_free(extra);
}
```